# Adding Teacher Bio to Events

Tags: wordpress, civievent

Working on a site that does regular classes with different teachers. The teacher bios are stored as pages in WordPress (could be moved to posts). We are looking for a way drop the bios into the event descriptions so when a new event is setup the bios can be part of the description. The site is in WordPress 4.7 & CiviCRM 4.6.

I have looked at a couple plugins (Insert Pages, Display-Posts) that allow you to drop content into other pages in WordPress but they don't seem to work in the CiviEvent Description field.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: I have a similar requirement where we want to have a 'log' added to an event that can be updated by users. A custom field is the obvious answer but the event config screen to update the field would not be suitable as it exposes critical data. Webforms for events are oriented toward contact signups - not at the event level but at the contact level. And profiles can't be used for events, can they? Searching for a solution here!

Comment: @AndyClark Your question is different enough at the technical level that it merits its own question - answers here won't be suitable for you!

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to inject a WordPress page/post into a CiviCRM event without some custom code.

If your event pages are dropped into WordPress pages/posts via a shortcode, you could add the bios above or below the shortcode.  This is the simplest approach, and if you wanted to reposition the bios to be within the "Description", that would be doable with 3-4 lines of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Events as a content type make more sense in WP, that way you can keep an Events Archive on the website if wanted too. And use CiviEvent for the Registrations part specifically. Then you can manage content all in WP for teachers and events. Using [Event Organiser](https://wordpress.org/plugins/event-organiser/) with this [CiviCRM integration plugin](https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-event-organiser) is useful to have Event listing in WP and link and manage registration with CiviEvent.